# How to create a customized list from pandas?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataframe as below :

```
Country Age     Dept    Card
India   Adult   Science A,B,C
India   Adult   Math    B,C,D
India   Adult   Social  E,D,C
```

Code to build the above DF :

```
pd.DataFrame ({'Country' : ['INDIA','INDIA','INDIA'],
                         'Age' : ['Adult','Adult','Adult'],
                         'Dept' : ['Science','Math','Social'],
                         'Card' : ['A,B,C','B,C,D','E,D,C']})
```

I wanted to get the list of lists from the values of the column - 'Card' as below :

```
[['A','B','C'], ['B','C','D'], ['E','D','C']]
```

I tried the below code :

```
lis1=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    lis=[]
    l=A.Card.iloc[i]
    lis.append(l)
    for i in range(0,len(df),len(df)):
        lis1.append(lis)
```

The output i get is as below :

```
[['A,B,C'], ['B,C,D'], ['E,D,C']]
```

If you can notice, that in my output I am not getting the parenthesis for individual elements. Can anyone help me to get the desired output?

Comment: Are you after: `df.Card.str.split(',').tolist()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this,

```
lis1=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    l=df.Card.iloc[i].split(',')
    lis1.append(l)
lis1
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'D', 'C']]
```

Comment: My reputation doesn't allows. But I have accepted ur answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
[list(a.split(',')) for a in df.Card.tolist()]
```

And the output is:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'D', 'C']]
```

Comment: Thanks Amit for your help.

Comment: My answer was before Abdur's. Haha, but no issues mate... have a nice year ahead.